# Map a calculated column to a managed property?

Tags: 2013, search, calculated-column, managed-property

I'm trying to map a `Calculated Column` of the type `Date and Time` to a `Managed Property` of the type `Date and Time` and then use it in a display template.

What i have done so far is:

1. Created a Calculated Column of the type Date and Time
2. Mapped the crawled property to a managed property of the type Date and Time (Using one of the empty managed properties available, Date00, Date01 etc)
3. Ran a full crawl
4. Mapped the managed property in my display template
5. Published a major version of the display template

However, using the F12 developer tool, i can see that the value for property is null. My concern is that the calculated column is not compatible to be used as a managed property.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I have found this thread but sadly, without an answer.

[Managed property for Calculated column of "Date Type" is not returning any results](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e00725f4-edc7-430b-8828-0fe8bcdd5567/managed-property-for-calculated-column-of-date-type-is-not-returning-any-results?forum=sharepointsearch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot map a Calculated column to a Date-Time type managed property in SharePoint. For all the calculated columns the managed property type should be text. That is why you will observe the value as **FieldType : value**. 
For example for a date time calculated column the value will be something like 
**datetime;#2017-07-05T22:00:00Z**